# Django passing parameter from views hangs server

Tags: django, oracle, django-views

I try to make simple web site with django, Oracle DB and django web server. And when I make query to db in django shell:

```
mylist=person.objects.filter(name='Anon')
```

everything works fine. Same when I use in views simple render

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,  'sos/index.html', {})
```

I get basic site. But when I try to pass parameters from query:

```
def index(request):
    mylist=person.objects.filter(name='Anon')
    return render(request,  'sos/index.html', {'mylist': mylist})
```

server hangs - no matter which browser I use, website is still connectig - only I can do is ctrl+C.

Comment: Django queries are not evaluated until you use them, so the first line is just preparing the query. What happens when you try to access an element of it, like mylist[0]? Django would evaluate the query then, and you'll be able to see if the problem is with the query. How large is person table? Is it in a remote db or local db?

Comment: It's remote db and is quite large. So is the person table. Hmmm...  when I add  
    mypers=mylist[0]   with just    
    return render(request,  'sos/index.html', {})   server hangs too.  And mylist has only one element, what I can check using this query in django shell

Comment: Well this suggests that the issue is more likely about the database query itself, not about passing parameters from query string or using this data in template. You can do many things to try improve query performance, but regardless of that, you may create a duplicate of that db on your local machine and use local db for development

Comment: Query performance is good - this query gives results in django shell, and in standalone python aplication too. Of course I could duplicate the database on local, but definitely its not the solution. For some reason the query (simpest possible) is good for django shell and not good for (local) server or browser